# Rails form_with ajax callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to use the latest `form_with` to send an Ajax post.

Here is what I did.

```
<%= form_with url: comments_path, data: { type: :json } do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_area :context, class: "rt-textarea mg-b-10" %>
  <%= form.submit "Submit", class: "btn-m btn-blue, id: "comment-submit" %>
<% end >

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#comment-submit').on('ajax:success', function(event, data) {
      console.log('GET RESPONSE!');
    });
  });
</script>
```

But when I send the form post, the console didn't print `GET RESPONSE!`. 
I checked the `Network` tab in google developer console, it did send the JSON object back. Is there anything I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I put the `id` in the wrong place.

I should put `id` in `form_with` tag instead of `submit` tag.

After I change to this line, it works perfectly.

```
<%= form_with url: comments_path, data: { type: :json }, id: "add_comment" do |form| %>
....
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `end` tag. The `form_with` may be like this:

```
<%= form_with url: users_path do |form| %>
      <%= form.text_field :email %>
      <%= form.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: No, I did add the end tag